# How to start event viewer (eventvwr) on windows 7 at a specific time?

Tags: windows-7, windows, event-viewer

Is there any way to start eventvwr at specific time. You can run it from `run` or `cmd` by typing `eventvwr`. I know that you could apply switched on the command itself e.g. `eventvwr /c:application`. Is there any way to start it at lets say 01/02/2017. This will greatly reduce time to find logs that I'm looking for xD.

Thank you xD.

Answer (score 0):

You can complete this action by using the "Task Scheduler" program.

Go to your "Start" icon and type in "Task" and it should appear as the first item in the list. From there a window should open up which is used to manage the tasks on your PC, on the left hand sidebar, you should see something called "Task Scheduler Library", click on this to see all your tasks.

To create a new task, click "Create Basic Task..." on the right hand side, this will open up the task wizard.

From here, give your task a name and description and click "Next".

Choose when you want the task to start and click "Next.

Enter a start date and recurrence option, then click "Next".

Click "Start a program" then "Next" again.

Enter C:\Windows\System32\eventvwr.exe in the program/script box, add any arguments you need then click "Next". Once done, click "Finish" and Event Viewer should now open daily at your chosen time.

Answer (score -1):

Try using Windows Task Scheduler and create a new task to start at the time you need or periodically.